# Как сделать рамку в камере Android?

Tags: java, android, камера, android-camera

Новичок в работе с Android, но сейчас стоит задача поставить рамку на камеру. Т.е. при открытии камеры была некая рамка (для корректировки пользователя), чтобы пользователю было понятно, что объект должен находится в пределах данной области.
[image: Пример использования рамки на камере]

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте `ImageView` с бэкграундом. `app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_outline"`

Пример лейаута с рамкой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
    android:id="@+id/preview_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#55000000"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flash_button"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash_2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_outline" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/capture_button"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_photo_btn" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Бэкграунд:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/yellow" />
</shape>
```

Comment: И получается, я должен вызвать активити камеры с модификациями ?

Comment: @Sss ну у вас же есть разметка для работы с камерой. в данном случае это androidx.camera.view.PreviewView. Просто добавьте туда ImageView и все